# Replacing repeated if statements with nested for loops in python?

Tags: python, loops

In the following code that I wrote, n = 4, and so there are five if statements, so if I would like to increase n to be, say 10, then there will be a lot of if's. Therefore my question: how can I replace all the if statements with something more elegant?

```
n, p = 4, .5  # number of trials, probability of each trial
s = np.random.binomial(n, p, 100)
# result of flipping a coin 10 times, tested 1000 times.

d = {"0" : 0, "1" : 0, "2" : 0, "3" : 0, "4" : 0 }

for i in s:
    if i == 0:
        d["0"] += 1
    if i == 1:
        d["1"] += 1 
    if i == 2:
        d["2"] += 1    
    if i == 3:
        d["3"] += 1
    if i == 4:
        d["4"] += 1
```

I tried using nested for loops,

```
 for i in s:
     for j in range(0,5):
         if i == j:
             d["j"] += 1
```

But i get this error:

```
d["j"] += 1

KeyError: 'j'
```

Comment: I'm assuming your indenting is off?

Comment: Why in the world are you using strings as keys in your dictionary? This would be so much easier using integer keys, or even a list.

Comment: The "j" you use is the string "j", not the actual number you want. Hence why it says keyerror.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with a comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(str(i) for i in s)
```

`Counter` works here because you're incrementing by one. However if you want it more general you could also use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(int)   # use int as factory - this will generate 0s for missing entries
for i in s:
    dd[str(i)] += 1  # but you could also use += 2 or whatever here.
```

or if you want it as plain dictionary, wrap it inside a `dict` call, for example:

```
dict(Counter(str(i) for i in s))
```

Both avoid `KeyError`s when the key isn't present yet and you avoid the double loop.

---

As a side note: If you want plain dicts you could also use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
d = {}  # empty dict
for i in d:
    d[str(i)] = d.get(str(i), 0) + 1
```

However `Counter` and `defaultdict` behave almost like plain dictionaries so there's almost no need for this last one, because it is (probably) slower and in my opinion less readable.

Comment: here you would usually just use `d.get`, no?

Comment: Note, you could use a `Counter there as well, `counts = Counter()`, then loop and `counts[str(j)] += 1` no need to handle missing values..

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah `dict.get` is much smarter here - I've edited it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You need to convert the integer to a string in the loop.

```
for i in s:
    for j in range(0,5):
        if i == j:
            d[str(j)] += 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively to Miket25's answer, you can actually use numbers as dictionary keys, like:

```
d = {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0 }

for i in s:
    # 0 <= i < 5 is the same as looking through and checking
    # all values 0-4 but more efficient and cleaner.
    if 0 <= i < 5:
        d[i] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this without importing any external module:

In one line

```
import numpy as np
n, p = 4, .5  # number of trials, probability of each trial
s = np.random.binomial(n, p, 100)
# result of flipping a coin 10 times, tested 1000 times.

d = {"0" : 0, "1" : 0, "2" : 0, "3" : 0, "4" : 0 }


[d.__setitem__(str(i),d[str(i)]+1) for i in s  for j in range(0, 5) if str(i) in d]



print(d)
```

output: (as it is random so can be anything)

```
{'1': 22, '3': 23, '0': 3, '4': 6, '2': 46}
```

Detailed solution:

```
for i in s:
    for j in range(0, 5):
        if str(i) in d:
            d[str(i)]+=1

print(d)
```

output:

```
{'4': 6, '0': 6, '3': 29, '1': 25, '2': 34}
```