# Deleting Items based on Keys in nested Dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, key

I have a dictonary that looks something like this:

```
{
    'key1': 
        {
            'a': 'key1', 
            'b': 'val1', 
            'c': 'val2'
        }, 
    'key2': 
        {
            'a': 'key2', 
            'b': 'val3', 
            'c': 'val4'
        }, 
    'key3': 
        {
            'a': 'key3', 
            'b': 'val5', 
            'c': 'val6'
        }
}
```

I trying to delete the elements in the nested dict based on the key "a" to get an output like this:

```
{
    'key1': 
        {
            'b': 'val1', 
            'c': 'val2'
        }, 
    'key2': 
        {
            'b': 'val3', 
            'c': 'val4'
        }, 
    'key3': 
        {
            'b': 'val5', 
            'c': 'val6'
        }
}
```

I wrote the following snippet for it:

```
for k in dict_to_be_deleted:
    del k["a"]
```

I keep getting Key Error: k not found. I tried the following method as well:

```
for i in dict_to_be_deleted:
    for k,v in i.items():
        if "a" in k:
            del i[k]
```

I get

```
Attribute Error: str object has no attribute items
```

But isn't it suppose to be a dictionary since `dict_to_be_deleted` is a nested dictionary? I am pretty confused with this. I greatly appreciate any pointers in this regard.

Answer (score 7):

An easy way is to use [`dict.pop()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) instead:

```
data = {
        'key1': 
            {
            'a': 'key1', 
            'b': 'val1', 
            'c': 'val2'
            }, 
        'key2': 
            {
            'a': 'key2', 
            'b': 'val3', 
            'c': 'val4'
            }, 
        'key3': 
            {  
            'a': 'key3', 
            'b': 'val5', 
            'c': 'val6'
            }
        }

for key in data:
    data[key].pop('a', None)

print(data)
```

Which Outputs:

```
{'key1': {'b': 'val1', 'c': 'val2'}, 'key2': {'b': 'val3', 'c': 'val4'}, 'key3': {'b': 'val5', 'c': 'val6'}}
```

The way `dict.pop()` works is that first checks if the key is in the dictionary, in this case `"a"`, and it removes it and returns its value. Otherwise, return a default value, in this case `None`, which protects against a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 5):

When you're iterating over a dictionary, `dict_to_be_deleted` you are only iterating over the keys. So in your second attempt, your `Attribute Error` is because `i` is the key, a string not the dictionary. How you could actually perform it would be to use `.values()` which iterates over the values instead.

```
for v in dict_to_be_deleted.values():
    del v["a"]
```

However, personally, instead of deleting the elements, I'd suggest following Ajax's method and building a new dictionary without the missing elements. Weird mutations like what we're doing here is an easy way to get bugs.

Comment: How is this "weird"?

Comment: Thanks a lot forthe quickhelp. I took your advice to create a new dict as well to ensure code efficiency.

Comment: @StefanPochmann "weird" is probably the wrong word, but always try and err on the side of avoiding possible side effects. If this gets wrapped up as some part of a function, suddenly arguments you pass in are getting changed and you might not realize it. However copying the dictionary is always going to be safe (as long as you're copying it deep enough).

Comment: @Ravi You create the whole thing from scratch... for **efficiency**?

Comment: @Ravi creating a new dict is not going to be more efficient, just better practice, less likely to lead to bugs down the line. In simple cases like this though better practice _almost always_ trumps efficiency.

Comment: @SCB Well don't do it in cases where you shouldn't. But if you think dictionaries shouldn't be modified, then why did you suggest `d[i] += 1` just a few hours ago? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48015627/1672429

Comment: @StefanPochmann I guess in that case my gut was more about creating a dictionary that replicated the `Counter` than actual dict mutation. Clarity wins out. (The actually just use the `Counter` answer to that question really was the best one). My feelings, be safe unless you have a reason not to.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it may be best to filter the contents of the dictionary:

```
d = {
'key1': 
    {
        'a': 'key1', 
        'b': 'val1', 
        'c': 'val2'
    }, 
 'key2': 
    {
        'a': 'key2', 
        'b': 'val3', 
        'c': 'val4'
    }, 
'key3': 
    {
        'a': 'key3', 
        'b': 'val5', 
        'c': 'val6'
    }
 }
new_d = {a:{c:d for c, d in b.items() if c != 'a'} for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'key3': {'c': 'val6', 'b': 'val5'}, 'key2': {'c': 'val4', 'b': 'val3'}, 'key1': {'c': 'val2', 'b': 'val1'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

well you can simply use two dictionary's function with list comprehension
**pop() & itervalues()**

> [value.pop('a', None) for value in d.itervalues()]
>
> print d
>
> **output** > {'key3': {'c': 'val6', 'b': 'val5'}, 'key2': {'c': 'val4', 'b': 'val3'}, 'key1': {'c': 'val2', 'b': 'val1'}}

**Benefit : it do not  occupy extra memory. cause we are not creating new dict here**

and if you are looking for simplicity @Ajax1234  answer is more descriptive

Answer (score 0):

Why you are deleting when you can extract what you need ? Here is collections.defaultdict(dict) approach:

```
data={
    'key1':
        {
            'a': 'key1',
            'b': 'val1',
            'c': 'val2'
        },
    'key2':
        {
            'a': 'key2',
            'b': 'val3',
            'c': 'val4'
        },
    'key3':
        {
            'a': 'key3',
            'b': 'val5',
            'c': 'val6'
        }
}

import collections

dict_1=collections.defaultdict(dict)
for key,value in data.items():
    for key_1,value_1 in value.items():
        if key!='a':
            dict_1[key][key_1]=value_1

print(dict_1)
```

output:

```
{
  "key1": {
    "b": "val1",
    "c": "val2"
  },
  "key2": {
    "b": "val3",
    "c": "val4"
  },
  "key3": {
    "b": "val5",
    "c": "val6"
  }
}
```