# Remove subdict based on condition from nested dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary containing (sub)dicts for "density" and "temperature". This is the structure:

```
profiles_dict =

{
    "density": {
        "elements": [
            {
                "layers": [
                    {
                        "top": 54.0,
                        "bottom": 3.75,
                        "value": 218.9
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "type": "density"
    },
    "temperature": {
        "elements": [
            {
                "layers": []
            }
        ],
        "type": "temperature"
    }
}
```

As one can see in the temperature subdict, the "layers" key contains an empty list as value. My goal is to create a loop/function that removes the dictionary `{"layers": []}`.

The result should look like this:

```
profiles_dict_new =

{
    "density": {
        "elements": [
            {
                "layers": [
                    {
                        "top": 54.0,
                        "bottom": 3.75,
                        "value": 218.9
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "type": "density"
    },
    "temperature": {
        "elements": [
            ],
        "type": "temperature"
    }
}
```

---

I have tried the following:

```
for k1, v1 in profiles_dict.items():
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            if type(v2) != list:
                continue
            for i in v2:
                for k3, v3 in i.items():
                    if v3 == []:
                        del(i)
```

With this loop, I can access `{'layers': []}`, however I don't know how to properly remove it form the dictionray.

The second approach is based on Ajax1234 solution ([Deleting Items based on Keys in nested Dictionaries in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017281/deleting-items-based-on-keys-in-nested-dictionaries-in-python))

```
profiles_dict_new = {d:{e:[{l:v for l, v in e.items() if v != []}]} for d, e in profiles_dict.items()}
print(profiles_dict_new)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-126f19ab7afd> in <module>
----> 1 profiles_dict_new = {d:{e:[{l:v for l, v in e.items() if v != []}]} for d, e in profiles_dict.items()}
      2 print(profiles_dict_new)

<ipython-input-11-126f19ab7afd> in <dictcomp>(.0)
----> 1 profiles_dict_new = {d:{e:[{l:v for l, v in e.items() if v != []}]} for d, e in profiles_dict.items()}
      2 print(profiles_dict_new)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Help is appreciated for either of the presented approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`del` does not delete objects: it deletes names. If multiple names refer to the same object, the other names persist.

Unbinding `i`, the loop variable, does nothing to the underlying list, and `i` just gets reassigned on the next iteration. You have to delete the actual list element `v2[index_of_i]` to get it removed from the list.

To be able to do that safely, you need to replace the original list or iterate over a copy of the list backwards. You can iterate forwards too, but then the index requires extra care to ensure that it accounts for preceding deleted elements.

Secondly, the loop over `i.items()` is counter-productive. You don't want to find a dictionary that has some key with an empty list in it. You want a dictionary that has exactly one key, so there's no need for a loop.

```
for k1, v1 in profiles_dict.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        if type(v2) != list:
            continue
        v1[k2] = [i for i in v2 if len(i) > 1 or next(i.values())]
```

Iterating backwards will allow you to keep the original list object:

```
for k1, v1 in profiles_dict.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        if type(v2) != list:
            continue
        n = len(v2) - 1  # capture before modifying
        for i, e in enumerate(reversed(v2)):
            if len(e) == 1 and not next(iter(e.values()))
                del v2[n - i]
```

If you iterate forward, you'll have to make a copy of the list to do it properly, and do extra bookkeeping for the index:

```
for k1, v1 in profiles_dict.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        if type(v2) != list:
            continue
        count = 0
        for i, e in enumerate(v2[:]):
            if len(e) == 1 and not next(iter(e.values()))
                del v2[i - count]
                count += 1
```

The expression `next(iter(...))` is a common idiom for getting a single element from something that has one element but can't be easily indexed, like a `dict` or `set`. Methods like `pop` are destructive: if you just wanted to check the element, you have to put it back. `next(iter(...))` lets you peek into the collection.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate and educative answer.

Comment: But for your last two suggested solutions I get the error again: TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not an iterator. I think that might have something to do with the fact that you have  e.values() as iterator of next()?

Comment: @linus fixed. It's generally `next(iter(...))`, not just `next(...)`. This is what happens when I post on mobile and can't test.

Comment: It's a somewhat common idiom for non-destructively getting the one element from an iterable that you don't necessarily know how to index. You can do it for a `set` too.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

instead of deleting assign empty list

you can try below code:

```
for k1, v1 in profiles_dict.items():
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            if type(v2) != list:
                continue
            for i in v2:
                for k3, v3 in i.items():
                    if v3 == []:
                        v1[k2] = []
```

Comment: That won't work if you have other dictionaries in there. If you only have one, I'd make the `break` after a successful assignment explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Many text but what you need is deleting a `dict` from a `list`?!
Your list is not `i` (element of list) it's `v2` so make sure to give your vars good names and change the `for` to a `while` cause deleting during iteration can cause problems.

```
for k1, v1 in profiles_dict.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        if type(v2) != list:
            continue
        i = 0
        while i < len(v2):
            for k3, v3 in v2[i].items():
                if v3 == []:
                    v2.pop(i) #remove k3 if v3 empty from list v2 at index i
                    i -= 1 #decrease index i
                    break #cause k3, v3 in v2[i].items() does not exist anymore
            i += 1
```

If an item `dict` in `list` `v2` contains more than one `k3` which can be NOT empty and you do NOT want to REMOVE it TOO you can store the empty ones for later in a new `list` `remove_keys`.
If `remove_keys` contains the same amout as the whole `dict` you can `.pop(index)` it from `v2` else `.pop(key)` all stored keys only from the current `dict` `v2[i]`.

```
for k1, v1 in profiles_dict.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        if type(v2) != list:
            continue
        i = 0
        while i < len(v2):
            remove_keys = [] #store k3 when v3 == []
            for k3, v3 in v2[i].items():
                if v3 == []:
                    remove_keys.append(k3)
            if len(remove_keys) == len(v2[i]): #if this would remove all keys
                v2.pop(i) #delete whole "empty" dict again...
                i -= 1
            else:
                for k3 in remove_keys: #remove stored keys from dict in v2 at i
                    v2[i].pop(k3)
            i += 1
```

Comment: This will remove non-empty dictionaries that have a single empty list in them

Comment: @Mad Physicist That's TRUE BUT not important here cause THAN I need to check may what items are exactly in the list and are they all dictst... so I IGNORED IT. Let me add a little detail to access this behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Being explicit is always good. Please don't shout.